# Laravel: error doing migration

Tags: database, laravel, migration

Sorry my poor english.
I'm learning Laravel. I've tried do a migration (php artisan migrate)
and i get this error message:

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homest
  ead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Laravel is trying connecting using user homestead... however my database config file specify using root as user to connect to the database:

[image]

What's going wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Go to .env(at the root of your project) and overwrite the Database information there. like this

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=lixo
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=segredo
```

Answer (score 1):

For homestead the default username is Homestead and password is secret.

Answer (score 0):

In .env file:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=DBName
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Close the laravel application server and restart again for clearing the cache.

```
 php artisan serve
```

try it!